# Call service for all controllers of website

Tags: php, service, controller, symfony4

Symfony 4 : Is there a way to call a service in all controllers of website ? 
Instead of call service in all methods of controllers (too much code duplication).
Put the service In the AbstractController ? (my need : if a specific table is empty in a route of app, it must be a redirectToRoute)

Comment: Can you explain "specific table is empty IN A ROUTE OF APP" - table in route?.. |You can use listeners, eg onKernelController event should be good for this

Comment: Simply : I don't want to write this in all my controllers :  
$foo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Bar::class)->findAll();
        if(!$foo) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('foo');
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can extend AbstractController

```
 class DefaultController1 extends MyController
    {
        public function default()
        {
             $this->logger ...
        }
    }

    class DefaultController2 extends MyController
    {
        public function default()
        {
             $this->logger ...
        }
    }

    class MyController extends AbstractController
    {
        public $logger;

        public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
        {
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to go about this in Symfony is with a Kernel event listener. I've got one for the `onKernelRequest` event to be able to log all webhooks - if the request is to a webhook route/url.

services.yml:

```
App\Subscribers\WebhookLoggingListener:
    arguments:
        # some arguments my listener needs
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

It is then called for every controller action request and does:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event): void
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        // don't do anything if it's not the master request
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if (!$this->isWebHook($request)) {
        return;
    }

    $this->logWebhookData($request);
}
```

Here, I see if it is *not* a webhook, and return. The isWebHook/logWebhookData can be replaced as you need to do any checks in a database, cache, or whatever you need.

More details about kernel event listeners are available on the [Symfony docs pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html).